# Apache log format: unable to log execution time

Tags: apache, logging

I tried to add execution time (time to serve page, to be more accurate) to log format of my apache server.

I did this

```
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %T/%D" combined

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

I added `%T/%D`

I did `apachectl reload` first then, because nothing changed, I also did a `apachectl restart`.

Anyway, my access.log entries are identical to before my change.

After useragent string there is nothing, I expected to see time to serve in second and then time to serve in microseconds.

What am I doing wrong?

My Server is quite old, could be important?

```
  "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.29 OpenSSL/1.0.1f`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that I cannot override the `combined` log format.

I simply changed the 'nickname' of new log format and it work !!!